# What are ways to synchronize LibreOffice dictionaries across multiple computers?

Tags: libreoffice, dropbox

Clean install of Ubuntu 19.10 with LibreOffice 6.3.3.2 as distributed with the OS.

I prefer to work on a desktop but will work on the same files on desktop and laptop. Also, it's duplicate effort having to 'Add to dictionary' a lot of community-specific language for a fresh install.

Presently I am going to LibreOffice Writer: Tools > Options > LibreOffice > Paths > Dictionaries > Edit > Add and the creating a new location in my Dropbox.

I think this will work, maybe some file locking issues though.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is what I did after a few days of tinkering.

Simply adding a Dropbox folder to Tools > Options > LibreOffice > Paths > Dictionaries wasn't working. "Add to Dictionary" would not come up in the context menu.

What I did was copy "home/.config/libreoffice/4/user/wordbook/standard.dic" to a folder in Dropbox then I included that folder in my dictionaries path. I restarted LibreOffice, although this may not be necessary. "Add to Dictionary" now comes up and the added words show up in my Dropbox dictionary which I confirmed by opening the dictionary in a text editor.

I will try this from a second computer when I can and will update.